# Javascript formdata: encrypt files before appending

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, form-data

I need to modify existing frontend (angular) code that involves uploading files to a server. Now the files need to be encrypted before being uploaded.

The current approach uses FormData to append a number of files and send them in a single request as shown below:

```
    function uploadFiles(wrappers){

        var data = new FormData();

        // Add each file
        for(var i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++){

            var wrapper = wrappers[i];
            var file = wrapper.file;
            data.append('file_' + i, file);
        }

        $http.post(uri, data, requestCfg).then(

        /*...*
```

I have been using Forge in other projects, but never in this sort of context and don't really see how to encrypt files on the fly and still append them as FormData contents.

Forge provides an easy API:

```
var key = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);
var iv = forge.random.getBytesSync(8);

// encrypt some bytes
var cipher = forge.rc2.createEncryptionCipher(key);
cipher.start(iv);
cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(someBytes));
cipher.finish();
var encrypted = cipher.output;
```

The backend recieves files using Formidable and all the file hanlding is already wired. I would thus like to stick to using the existing front-end logic but simply insert the encryption logic. In that, it's not the entire formdata that must be encrypted... I haven't found a good lead yet to approach this.

Suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: What is the goal here? Are you trying to protect the files in transit or to protect the files from the person controlling the web server?

Comment: not your question, but have you looked at the native [crypto](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) API? (in case your users have reliably recent browsers, it provides real cryptographic randomness and built-in algorithms)

Comment: Hi @Quentin, indeed, the remote server must not be able to read the contents. It's an intermediate node between the browser and the actual processing engine. Medical data, seems touchy regarding potential misuse.

Comment: Hi @Touffy, no I haven't, forge haas been used on the recieving end too, so I began with that... I'll have a look at the cyrpto api you mentionned. Maybe wil lsolve my issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution and added the decrypt code as well. This adds a layer of async code.

```
        function appendFile(aFile, idx){

            // Encrypt if a key was provided for this protocol test
            if(!key){
                data.append('dicomfile_' + idx, file);
                appendedCount++;
                onFileAppended();
            }

            else{
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(){

                    // 1. Read bytes
                    var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
                    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);    // byte array aka uint8

                    // 2. Encrypt
                    var cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher('AES-CBC', key);
                    cipher.start({iv: iv});
                    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(bytes));
                    cipher.finish();

                    // 3. To blob (file extends blob)
                    var encryptedByteCharacters = cipher.output.getBytes();     // encryptedByteCharacters is similar to an ATOB(b64) output
                    // var asB64 = forge.util.encode64(encryptedBytes); 
                    // var encryptedByteCharacters = atob(asB64);

                    // Convert to Blob object
                    var blob = byteCharsToBlob(encryptedByteCharacters, "application/octet-stream", 512);

                    // 4. Append blob
                    data.append('dicomfile_' + idx, blob, file.name);

                    // Decrypt for the sake of testing
                    if(true){

                        var fileReader = new FileReader();
                        fileReader.onload = function() {
                            arrayBuffer = this.result;
                            var bytez = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                            var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);
                            decipher.start({iv: iv});
                            decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(bytez));
                            decipher.finish();
                            var decryptedByteCharacters = decipher.output.getBytes();
                            var truz = bytes === decryptedByteCharacters;
                            var blob = byteCharsToBlob(decryptedByteCharacters, "application/octet-stream", 512);
                            data.append('decrypted_' + idx, blob, file.name + '.decrypted');

                            appendedCount++;
                            onFileAppended();       
                        };
                        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
                    }

                    else{

                        // z. Resume processing
                        appendedCount++;
                        onFileAppended();                           
                    }
                }

                // Read file
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(aFile);
            }
        }

function onFileAppended(){

            // Only proceed when all files were appended and optionally encrypted (async) 
            if(appendedCount !== wrappers.length) return;
            /* resume processing, upload or do whathever */
```