# How to convert HTML5 FormData object to raw payload with frontend javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, ecmascript-6, multipartform-data

In my browser side script, I want to get the entire POST request payload stream.

But when the body is a FormData object, especially when it contains a file blob, is there any easy way to make it?

> The reason for doing this is that I want to make AES encrypt on the whole request body, using axios request interceptor.

For example:

I want to convert the FormData object:

```
const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('example.png', file) // here file is a file object from the file input object
```

Into the below content:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryMV9GYQ2pcwRJ6XAA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="example.png"
Content-Type: image/png
<<blob bytes>>

------WebKitFormBoundaryMV9GYQ2pcwRJ6XAA--
```

Is there any easy way to make it or any exists npm packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript formdata: encrypt files before appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134166/javascript-formdata-encrypt-files-before-appending)

Comment: Thank you, but I think it may be a bit inconvinient if I implement the whole procedure myself. I'd rather expecting a exists library to make it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it will really help your end goal, but for what you ask, you can create a new [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object from this FormData and consume it as plain text:

```js
(async () => {
  const file = await new Promise((res) => document.createElement('canvas').toBlob(res));
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('example.png', file, 'example.png');
  const resp = new Response(fd);
  console.log( await resp.text() );
})();
```